# How to get a query by selecting rows in the TableA with a particular exclusion in TableB

Tags: mysql, sql

TableA

```
clientId    clientPassword
1           1234
2           1234
3           1234
```

TableB

```
clientId        clientCode
1               TRN
2               ABC
3               CDE
3               TRN
```

What would be the query to select TableA.clientPassword with only those clientID which does not have 'TRN' in TableB.clientCode ?

Part of a complex query but simplified to get my question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic `not exists`;

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableB b
                  where a.clientId = b.clientId and b.clientcode = 'TRN'
                 );
```

More here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not exists works perfectly and is the logically straight forward way to write this but isn't always the most performant option. Using a not in relies on the DB system to figure out it can flatten the query out to avoid running it row by row. With this simple of a query the DB system likely will figure it out but you can write it in a flattened way.

```
SELECT a.* 
    FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.clientId = b.clientid 
                                    AND b.clientcode = 'TRN'
WHERE b.ClientId IS NULL
```

To explain this a bit the left join will join table B to table A where the ID's match and the clientcode is 'TRN' but will keep all entries in table A and have NULLs for table B when a record doesn't exist with 'TRN' so then the is null check is equivalent to the not exists in the other query but avoids the row by row checking of a correlated sub-query and should be much faster.

Comment: Interesting variation ! Thanks Evan.

Comment: *has to be  run individually for each row*: not true.  There is no rule constraining an SQL implementation to a particular *way* to do something.  And most DBMSs in fact "flatten" correlated subqueries when feasible.  If you find an example in your DBMS of two logically equivalent minimal queries in which a correlated subquery performs substantially different from an outer join, and it's not documented, I'd suggest submitting a problem report.  It's not a bug, but it is an optimization opportunity.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden I edited my post to soften it and allow for DBMS optimization of the query.